# You must log in to answer this closed question

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

The Meta site tells visitors who aren't logged in that they  need to log in to answer. Unfortunately, that won't help, since it's closed. So let's get rid of the message, as it doesn't apply.

> [image: The line "You must log in to answer this question" appears directly below the "closed as not a real question" banner when not logged in.]

Comment: you must be logged in to answer a meta question.

Comment: @Sathya Yes. Note the rest of the screen shot.

Comment: which is? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Logging in won't help.

Comment: Ah damn, right. Gotcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed soon. I'll update when it's ready.

Update:  fixed now.